# Can't locate element in selenium. XPath, css selectors, I've tried everything

Tags: python, selenium, automation

```html
Impressions
<div class="ellipsis _1ha3" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-display="overflow" data-tooltip-text-direction="auto">11,483</div>

Clicks

<div class="ellipsis _1ha3" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-display="overflow" data-tooltip-text-direction="auto">379</div>
```

I'm currently stuck. I'm running two pieces of identical code to pull metrics from fb ad manager, and although the top code works fine, the second code (the one trying to find clicks) can't seem to find the element i'm looking for. I've tried xpath, css_selectors, everything, and still can't seem to find out why I can't locate that element. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

## Impressions

```
impressions = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ads_pe_container"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]')
impressions_text = impressions.text
impressions_attribute_value = impressions.get_attribute('value')
impressions = ('{0}'.format(impressions_text))
print(impressions)
```

## Clicks

```
clicks = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ads_pe_container"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div/div/div[1]')
clicks_text = clicks.text
clicks_attribute_value = clicks.get_attribute('value')
clicks = ('{0}'.format(clicks_text))
print(clicks)
```

I'm expecting for #click to return a number like #impressions did, but it can't seem to find the element. I've even tried switching frames to no avail. The #impressions is located in DOM window, so that wasn't an issue. Any help would be appreciated.

[a copy of the element #clicks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWEj5.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us the HTML that you are targetting, _as text_. Are you certain that the website works wihout Javascript enabled?

Comment: I just added the html for the element I'm targetting. I'm not too familiar with Javascript, but I know that the #impressions pulled perfectly. Not too sure why #clicks isn't doing the same. please let me know if there's anything else I can do to help. Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

you shold always try and trim selectors, make them as thin as possible.

as selector you should use:

This selector will match exact className:

```
xpath('//div[@class="ellipsis _1ha3"][x]')
```

or

This selector will match elements class where it contains this chars:

```
xpath('//div[contains(@class, "ellipsis _1ha3")][x]')
```

- x is the position of retrieved dom elements, starts from 1, ([1] will select first occurence and so on).

Answer (score 0):

The variable for occurrence must be placed after the complete xpath:

```
xpath('(//div[contains(@class, "ellipsis _1ha3")])[x]')
```

or

```
xpath( ' (//div[@class='ellipsis _1ha3'])[x]')
```

You can try the xpath in console of Chrome , as mentioned below:

```
$x("(//div[contains(@class,'ellipsis _1ha3')])[x]")
```

If the class name has to be matched exactly then:

```
$x("(//div[@class='ellipsis _1ha3'])[x]")
```